# php explode function error

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting this error message: **Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\evantechbd\secure\content\right_cat_pr.php on line 18**. I want get news_id and cat_name from a table.

**Here is the html form:**

```
<?php
include "db.php";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news_cat");
?>

<form action="right_cat_pr.php" method="post" name="right_cat">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
<tr>    
<td>News Category Name</td>
<td>
<select name="cat_name">

<?php 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $new_id = $row['news_id'];
    $cat_name = $row['cat_name'];
?>
<option "<?php echo $row['news_id'] . '|' . $row['cat_name'] ?>"><?php echo 
$row['cat_name']; ?></option>
<?php   
}
?>
</select>    

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**Here is the process page:**

```
<?php   
include "db.php";
$row = explode('|', $_POST['cat_name']);
$news_id = $row[0]; // cat_id
$cat_name = $row[1];            

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO right_cat VALUES ('','$news_id','$cat_name')");
        if($query)
        {
        echo "Successfully Inserted your News Category<br/>";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "Something is wrong to Upload";
        }   

?>
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but you've got an SQL injection vulnerability there. `INSERT INTO right_cat VALUES ('','$news_id','$cat_name')`, what happens if $news_id is `ffff'); DROP * FROM *;--`?

Comment: @Seventoes +1 on the comment for resisting the urge to reference Little Bobby Tables :) ... as for the question ... The error message means you're referencing an array key that doesn't exist on line 18. If you aren't 100% sure that an array key will exist, you should check that it is valid with `empty` or `isset` before referencing it.

Comment: Thanks @Seventoes. So what should i do to prevent sql injection?

Comment: Use http://php.net/mysql_escape_string on ANY and ALL data that comes from the user. I've also found some good guidelines with a quick Google search, from the University of Rhode Island: http://www.uri.edu/webservices/phpGuideline.html#sqlInject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the option value with `<option value="<?php echo $row['news_id'] . '|' . $row['cat_name'] ?>"`